how to use fiddler classic in docker within an xvfb
I have a crawler project using selenium and chrome. I need to crawl, take screenshot and record videos for the crawler using xvfb in docker.
My Goal is to

run docker
start the xvfb
open fiddler classic using subprocess and capture the network logs.
run crawler script with chrome browser.
record both the browser and the fiddler in xvfb as a video.

Code for fiddler:
fiddler_path = os.path.abspath("/app/Fiddler/Fiddler.exe")
def open_fiddler(fiddler_path):
fiddler_process = subprocess.Popen([fiddler_path])
return fiddler_process
I have used correct path for the fiddler, but I'm getting error:
open_fiddler()
           File "/app/fiddler_control.py", line 8, in open_fiddler
           fiddler_process = subprocess.Popen([fiddler_path])
           File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
           self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
           File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
           raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
           FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: C:/.../Fiddler.exe

I have tried to copy the fiddler from windows to the fiddler folder in docker containing the Fiddler.exe. Also, checked the fiddler in /app with ls -l /app/Fiddler. It is present in the folder app and still not accessible like in windows.
How can I access the fiddler installed on windows to run in docker within xvfb?

The people in the project are using fiddler and they keep screen record of the crawling browser and the fiddler. They wish to achieve the same for headless mode on a server. So, I found xvfb for this. But using fiddler and pyautogui with xvfb is difficult. If it's achievable, then let me know.

What docker image do you use? If it is a Linux base image then Fiddler can not run in it.

Yes, it is a wsl ubuntu based container and image. I want to use the fiddler in this container with xvfb. I can run browser in xvfb. How can I use fiddler too?

Fiddler is a Windows program. It does not run on Linux/Ubuntu.
